# Viewpager not retaining views properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, retain, fragmentpageradapter

I have a SherlockFragment thats inflating a layout containing a viewpager that allows me to swipe to a number of tab-fragments which I have created.
On the first time this fragment gets attached to my activity everything works fine and as expected, but if i go back and re-enter the fragment, the viewpager or its adapter *(that looks like this: "TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener")* are causing problems:

1. The view of the fragment stored in the viewpager is not visible
2. Actually I have 4 Tabs, if I set "setOffscreenPageLimit" nothing becomes visible in the  viewpager on recreation, whatever I am doing;
   if "setOffscreenPageLimit" is **not** set the views inside the viewpager are only shown if i swipe at least two tabs left or right.
3. Also it seems like the pager is now skipping some tabs while swiping, if "setOffscreenPageLimit" is **not used**.

Thanks for any ideas that could solve this problem.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "using" or "setting" `setOffscreenPageLimit`. The method `setOffscreenPageLimit` takes a positive integer which indicates how many pages to the left and right you want to store in memory. If you never call this method, the default value will be 1 (which should work fine). How are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. After some research I found the following thread:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19001

Answer #10 was what fixed my issue.